# Execute provider riverpod in flutter

Tags: riverpod, riverpod-annotation

how to run watch provider riverpod annotations from the main() of flutter ??
riverpod requires context ref, but I can't see it in the riverpod documentation ,
try providerscope override

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 
  runApp(
    
   const ProviderScope(
 --- HERE 
   child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final appRouter = ref.watch(appRouterProvider);

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: appRouter,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme().getTheme(),
      title: 'Push APP',
    );
  }
}
```